# Linear algebra question about combination linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Suppose that $T : M_{2×2}(\Bbb R) \rightarrow U_{2×2}(\Bbb R)$ and $S : U_{2×2}(\Bbb R) \rightarrow P_3$ are linear transformations.
Then the composition map $S \circ T : M_{2×2}(\Bbb R) \rightarrow P_3$ is never one-to-one.

To prove this is wrong, I have created a transformation $T$ and $S$ such that the standard matrix for the transformation $S \circ T$ has a pivot in every column, and thus, one-to-one. However, I am not sure if I am on the right track or missing something, as this answer seems too easy.

Comment: Please help us to help you by explaining your notation. $M_{2\times2}(\Bbb{R})$ could well be the set of of $2 \times 2$ matrices with elements in $\Bbb{R}$ and $U_{2\times2}(\Bbb{R})$ might be the set of upper-triangular matrices. I can't hazard a guess about $P_3$. You need to tell us what the notations mean in your context.

Comment: @RobArthan Hmm... Polynomials of degree at most 3? Then it would be $\Bbb R^4\to \Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^4$.

Comment: @RobArthan U2×2(ℝ) is the set of upper triangular matrices and P3 is the set of polynomials of degree at most 3.

Comment: @A.Γ. Actually, I knew that with the obvious guess about the meaning $M$ and $U$ it didn't matter what $P_3$ meant, but the OP should have been more conscientious.

Comment: @RobArthan I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Following your comment clarifying the notation:

$M_{2\times2}(\Bbb{R})$ ($2\times2$ matrices with real number entries) is a $4$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{R}$. $U_{2\times2}(\Bbb{R})$ (upper-triangular $2\times2$ matrices with real number entries) is a $3$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{R}$.

Any linear transformation $T : M_{2\times2}(\Bbb{R}) \to U_{2\times2}(\Bbb{R})$ must have a kernel of dimension at least $1$. So for any real vector space $V$ and any linear transformatiom $S : U_{2\times2}(\Bbb{R}) \to V$, the composite $S \circ T$ will have a non-trivial kernel and hence will not be one-one.